# call function once again after failure, without duplicate lines?

Tags: php, dry

I have what is probably an over-engineering question. I have some PHP code that logs messages to a file. We've been having a problem with the file having the wrong perms from time to time. While we're troubleshooting that, I am writing a work-around for that in the logging function, changing the unix perms and owners on the log file.

So my code looks like this:

```
function log($message) {
  if ( FALSE === file_put_contents(log_path(), $message) ) {
    chown(log_path(), 'apache');
    chgrp(log_path(), 'www-data');
    chown(log_path(), 0770);

    // now I'm repeating this line
    if ( FALSE === file_put_contents(log_path(), $message) ) {
      // log error to database
      db_log($message);
    }
  }
}
```

In the interest of DRY, can I somehow change the code to avoid repeating the line `if ( FALSE === file_put_contents(log_path(), $message) ) {`? Of course, I can't use recursion, because that would go on forever.

Comment: If the second `if` condition requires the three `ch` lines in order to work properly, then your code is already DRY.

Comment: why would recursion go on forever? You're not doing recursion right if it's endless.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Well, if I did a simple `log($message)` within the function, it would continuously try to log, then fail, log, then fail, etc. I could put a static variable, or add an argument as a termination condition, but I never want it to recurse more than once anyway. Have I saved anything, then, over just repeating the line? I suppose again I come back to the thought that I am probably over-thinking things.

Comment: Definitely overthinking, but hey, just for grins I gave you a solution anyway just  as an exercise.

Comment: Logging is hard, let's go shopping.  `function log($message) { syslog(LOG_INFO, $message); }` is a far better answer, and it puts the hard part in `rsyslog` _et al._, where it belongs.

Comment: Is it me, or is the work-around bound to fail? If you can't write to the file, what are the chances that you can change its ownership and permissions?

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus it's not you, but the circumstances of our problem. When the process is activated by the website, the process runs under apache. When activated by cron, it runs as root. When root creates the first log file at the beginning of the day, apache does not have permissions to write to it through the rest of the day. However, if the process has a routine to change the permissions of the file, then, when running as root from cron, it can change the permissions so that apache can write to it later on. Our solution anyways was to change certain cron jobs to run as apache.

Comment: @user1936 exactly. So when run as root, it can write, so never does the chown/chmod/chgrp. When run as apache, it can not write, so tries the ch* which would probably fail, and then tries to write to it again which will then also fail. Better indeed is running the crons as apache as well if possible. L

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus Oh, I understand the mistake now :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's unnecessary, but if you want to dry this up:

```
function and_($now, $then) {
    return function($seed) use($now, $then) {
        return $now($seed) && $then($seed);
    };
}

function or_($now, $else) {
    return function($seed) use($now, $else) {
        return $now($seed) || $else($seed);
    };
}

function write_message($message) {
  return file_put_contents(log_path(), $message);
}

function fix_file($message) {
  chown(log_path(), 'apache');
  chgrp(log_path(), 'www-data');
  chown(log_path(), 0770);
  return TRUE;
}

function log_($message) {
    $log = or_('write_message', and_('fix_file', or_('write_message', 'db_log')));
    $log($message);
}
```

Comment: I find it strangely concerning that while I can follow the purpose of this quite easily on the first reading, I had to read it about 5 times to figure out how it does it.

Comment: @Jules the fact that it's easy to see what it does is the point - this is how this style of coding enhances maintainability. You can quickly and easily *reason* about what it's doing, but *how* it's doing it may be a little more involved. Since code is read wayy more often than it's written, this is a good thing. You'll spend a bit of time reading and re-reading the code you're going to change in maintenance anyways, so that it takes some effort to understand the how is not really a problem in my experience. You'll rarely edit such code though, you'll read it and know what it does and move on.

Comment: Please don't ever do this.

Comment: @CorbinMarch to be fair- that's my rule of thumb for people not used to the style. When you're familiar with the style, it's just as easy to edit but for people unfamiliar just see english that's easy to understand but the implementation uses a variety of unfamiliar abstraction techniques regarding functional composition. When you have seen it enough times to be familiar with such techniques; they're very easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely wanted to, you could do this:

```php
function log($message)
{
  for($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i)
  {
    if ( FALSE !== file_put_contents(log_path(), $message) )
    {
      return;
    }
    if($i == 0)
    {
      chown(log_path(), 'apache');
      chgrp(log_path(), 'www-data');
      chown(log_path(), 0770);
    }
    else
    {
      // log error to database
      db_log($message);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't like it, however... Just a simple function call? Well, it is OK. If it was a more complex code you had to execute before being able to make a decision, I'd write a separate function for **this**, returning true or false, and have it called twice, right as you did with the file_put_contents function.

Answer (score 0):

A couple possibilities that haven't been mentioned:

1. If setting the permissions is always acceptable, always set the permissions, avoiding the first 'if' entirely.  Especially since this is a workaround.
2. Check the permissions, setting them if necessary, then call file_put_contents(...). This has the added benefit of distinguishing a permissions error from a real error in the call to file_put_contents(...), which may help with debugging.